# How to get an element it's index in PROTRACTOR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

It's my first question here and I've been trying to use Protractor to do end to end test.
I need to get the first element from this group of code. As you can see, I have the same class and the same sub-class for these 3 element. So I thought to get it by using the index.

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Número</label>
            <input class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty" type="number">
          </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Inicio Vigência</label>
        <input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" type="date" value="">
      </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Fim Vigência</label>
        <input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" type="date" value="">
      </div>
```

I've trying:

```
var numero = element.all(by.className('form-group')).get(2).all(by.tagName('input'));
        numero.sendKeys(aux2);
```

But it's not working. Protractor doesn't sentkeys in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you need the first element, just use `.first()` instead of `.get(2)`:

```
var numero = element.all(by.className('form-group')).first().all(by.tagName('input'));
numero.sendKeys(aux2);
```

Note that you can locate the desired input element in one go with a CSS selector and the [`first-of-type` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo):

```
var numero = $(".form-group:first-of-type input");
numero.sendKeys(aux2);
```

Or, via [`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type):

```
var numero = $(".form-group:nth-of-type(1) input");
numero.sendKeys(aux2);
```

`$` here is a [convenient shortcut](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$) to `element(by.css())`.

---

Another way to approach this problem would be not to rely on the form group indexes (which actually sounds fragile - imagine the UI would change and the form controls would simply be re-arranged) and, instead, locate the `input` element based on it's label:

```
var numero = element(by.xpath("//label[. = 'Número']/following-sibling::input"));
numero.sendKeys(aux2);
```

Comment: Actually it's just an example, I have more than 10 elements in this group, that's why I've been trying to use get(index).

Comment: @paulotarcio okay, updated the answer with different ways to solve the problem. Hope that helps.

Comment: @alexcxe The last one works perfectly. Thanks for you help.